# StatFs methods getTotalBytes and getFreeBytes not returning correct values

Tags: java, android

I'm writing an Android app in which I need to display the total internal storage space and the free space. I've used the `StatFs` class for it and I've used the methods `getTotalBytes()` and `getFreeBytes()`. I process the result and convert it into gigabytes. But the results given by these methods do not match the actual values (found by many file managing apps).

I've tried different methods that return the storage space, but I always keep getting the same result: they don't match.

```
private final static double noBytesInOneGB = 1073741824.0;
StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
double totalSpaceInGB = stat.getTotalBytes() / noBytesInOneGB;
double freeSpaceInGB = stat.getFreeBytes() / noBytesInOneGB;
```

If I run the app on my phone, this code returns the total storage as 49.55 GB and the free storage as 40.02 GB. If I used a file manager app, it says the total storage is 53.32 GB and the free storage is 42.37 GB.

**UPDATE:** I figured out what was wrong. Apparently, all the file managers treat 1 kB as 1000 bytes and not 1024 bytes. I don't know how this is accurate, but I went with it anyway to be consistent with everything else. Changing noBytesInOneGB's value to 1000000000.0 made everything consistent.

Comment: You should add answer to your own post and mark it as selected. :)

Comment: I was using this and found it was giving inaccurate readings, but in a very big way. e.g. 500 GBs instead of 4 KB. Any idea if `StatFs` works properly on individual directories?